# Facelets tab lib not recognised by Eclipse/Tomcat 6

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets, myfaces

I included this in my index.jsp JSF file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ui" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"%>
```

and Eclipse underlines the URL, hovering gives this:

```
Cannot find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
```

Deploying and trying to start Tomcat 6 using the Tomcat plugin causes this:

```
|STDOUT| 2010-03-03 17:57:29,872 | INFO  | [main]: Serialization provider : class org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.serial.DefaultSerialFactory
    |STDOUT| 2010-03-03 17:57:29,904 | INFO  | [main]: ServletContext 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\myapp\' initialized.
    |STDOUT| 2010-03-03 17:57:29,904 | INFO  | [main]: Checking for plugins:org.apache.myfaces.FACES_INIT_PLUGINS
    03-Mar-2010 17:57:29 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Error listenerStart
    03-Mar-2010 17:57:29 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
    SEVERE: Context [/myapp] startup failed due to previous errors
```

...

```
03-Mar-2010 17:57:30 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:804)
```

My web.xml contains this

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

My face-config.xml contains this

```
    <application>
    <!-- tell JSF to use Facelets -->
    <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

And my application build has the latest JSF 2.0.2 jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar.  I've also got MyFaces 1.2.8 and all the latest commons jars.  The app was building fine til I upgraded JSF.  I would at least expect a run time error but here Eclipse cannot see the taglib.  What else could I be missing?

**EDIT**

For full information - I took out Mojarra and left in Myfaces.  This meant I needed to remove this from my `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

and replace it with the equivalent for myfaces:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot mix multiple implementations of an abstract specification. Use either Mojarra OR MyFaces as an implementation of the JSF specification. Then there are JSF component libraries like RichFaces, Tomahawk, etc..etc.. which you can just keep using on top of one of the JSF implementations. Bozho has it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not mix JSF 2.0 with JSF pre-2.0. It may lead to unexpected results (like the one above).

Choose a JSF 2.0 implementation (mojarra as it seems) and remove all myfaces and facelets libraries.

Comment: Bozho, I've actually used myFaces, but you're right and that's my development naivety again.  I've learned a lot from you and BalusC over the last month - thanks very much indeed guys.

Comment: @Bozho are you sure that facelets has to be removed as well? As far as I understand JSF RI (Mojarra) has nothing to do with Facelets.. They are independent libraries.

Comment: @yegor256 - JSF 2.0 has facelets by default. See Mark Lewis' answer. For JSF 1.2 you are correct - facelets is needed in a separate jar.

Comment: @Bozho hm... In my case they work together: [pom.xml](http://trac.fazend.com/rempl/browser/rempl/trunk/rempl/rempl-oss/pom.xml)

Comment: @yegor256 - lucky classloading ? :) Try removing the facelets jar.

Comment: @Bozho tried: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler`

Comment: @yegor256 - remove the handler from `faces-config.xml`

Comment: @Bozho now I have another problem in JSFUnit: `java.lang.NullPointerException` at [getCurrentViewID()](http://trac.fazend.com/rempl/browser/rempl/trunk/rempl/rempl-oss/src/test/java/com/rempl/oss/helpers/HomeXhtmlTest.java) (line 30).

Comment: @yegor256 - it might be a JSFUnit issue. If the application is running fine apart from JSFUnit.

Comment: Yeah, works fine outside of JSFUnit-empowered container... Ok, I will investigate further. But with explicit `facelets` dependency (as it is now) everything works fine.

Comment: The problem was that my `faces-config.xml` was from JSF 1.2 (according to its DTD), but was not specifying the Facelets handler. I fixed the header of XML, and removed `facelets` dependency from `pom.xml`. Works perfectly now. Bozho, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well that's annoying.  I read in a couple of places that the new Mojarra release embedded facelets.  I added jsf-facelets-1.1.14.jar to my build and it deployed ok.